# Carplay automatically launch previously used app and play sound

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I have an app that plays sounds, and whenever my phone connect to carplay, it automatically start playing sounds in my app. Is there a way to disable this from being launch automatically?

Comment: How are you configuring your audio session?

Comment: What do you mean? Is there a setting for CarPlay there? I set the category to playback and mixWithOther is set to false

Comment: No, there isn't a CarPlay setting, but the system will try and transfer active playback to the car when you connect; things like podcasts, music etc. if the core purpose of your app isn't audio playback then you should use a category of ambient or solo ambient.

Comment: I just don't want it to automatically start playing in the car

Comment: Then as far as I know you will need to use a different playback category.

Comment: Thats pretty dumb

Comment: Take it up with Apple. I guess they figure most people want the audio that is currently playing on their phone or was last playing when they were in their car to start playing again when they reconnect t their car.